# Unable to download a file using org.apache.cordova.file-transfer

Tags: cordova, plugins, file-transfer

I am building a phonegap application for android. I want to download a file using plugins like file and file transfer.
I added both the plugins using -

cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer

It successfully added the plugins too.Then I added permissions like READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE & WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE for android. I updated the config.xml file too. But even then when I execute the code, I get the following error-

Uncaught Reference Error: LocalFileSystem is not defined.

My code is-

```
function fileManager() {};

fileManager.download = function (source, callback) {
    var fileName = fileManager.fileName(source);

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,0, 
        function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
            alert('success');
            fileSystem.root.getFile(
                fileName, {create: true, exclusive: false}, 
                function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
                    //var sPath = fileEntry.fullPath.replace(fileName,"");
                    var sPath = 'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/'
                    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
                  fileTransfer.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
                  if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
                  loadingStatus.setPercentage(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total);
                  } else {
                  loadingStatus.increment();
                 }
               };
                    fileEntry.remove();

                    fileTransfer.download (
                        encodeURI(source),
                        sPath + fileName,
                        function(theFile) {
                            console.log("download complete: " + theFile.toURI());
                            callback(theFile.toURI());
                        },
                        function (error) {
                             alert('error');
                            console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                            console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                            console.log("upload error code: " + error.code);
                        }
                    );
                }, function(e){
                     alert('error');
                });
        }, function (e) {
             alert('error');
        });
    };

fileManager.fileName = function(source) {
    var paths = source.split('/');
    return paths[paths.length - 1];
}
```

I tried many possible solutions but none of them served my purpose. Please help.
                      Thanks and regards.

Comment: did you install file plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this straightforward solution?

```
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.download(
    "http://www.something.com/test.zip", // what u download
    "/sdcard/test.zip",// this is the filename as well complete url
    function(entry) {
        alert("success"); alert(JSON.stringify(entry));

    }, 
    function(err) {
        alert(err); alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
);
```

You can also try to refer to this link:
http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/sorry-for-being-gone-so-long-vacation.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, but I am not sure that device would have a sd card or not. So I want to save this in localFileSystem. And the link also contain the same code that I have gone through. I am still getting an error. I guess the issue is with plugin addition. It is not added properly. But I followed all the steps. Still there is an issue.

Comment: I tried your solution too. Now I am getting the following error-     Uncaught ReferenceError: FileTransfer is not defined

Comment: You definitely have problems with plugin installed. You should remove plugin and install again. To store your data in local storage, you can refer to this link: https://github.com/Icenium/sample-localstorage

Comment: Sir, I did that too. I removed the plugin and then again installed it. But I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: Create new test project, add plugin and try that full html example https://github.com/jcfischer/pgkitchensink/blob/master/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file-transfer/docs/filetransfer/filetransfer.md